# How MySql distinguishes the different of temporary table between connections?

Tags: mysql, temp-tables

I read an article (https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/temporary-tables-in-sql-server/) about how SQL Server distinguishes two temporary tables with the same name but is created in 2 different connection. They do it by adding a numeric string to each local temporary table name left-padded by underscore characters.

I wonder how MySQL can handle the situation above (make a differents of two temp tables with the same name in two local connections)? Is it use the  same  approach like  SQL does?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL handles temporary tables internally by generating unique pseudo-random filenames for tables. Here's an example with the MyISAM engine:

```
mysql> create temporary table test.foo (i int) engine=myisam;
mysql> exit
```

Now let's see what was created in MySQL's tmpdir:

```
$ ls /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n000009800002_/T/

#sql6f_200000013_2.MYD  #sql6f_200000013_2.MYI
```

I tried this test with a temp InnoDB table, but that storage engine does not create visible files (at least not in version 8.0.3 which is what I have installed right now). I guess the temp table is created in the system tablespace `ibdata1`.

MySQL has some internal mapping of logical table name `test.foo` to the respective physical table name. This way each session can have its own distinct table, even though other sessions have a table of the same name.

Comment: In case of innodb the behaviour depends on the file per table setting. If this is false, then the shared temporary tablespace is used. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-temporary-tablespace.html Regardless of this setting, the actual file name is random. Mysql associates a file id with the name you provided and that id is used to lookup up the random file name.

Comment: @Shadow, my innodb_file_per_table=1, but I see no file when I create an InnoDB temp table. I suspect things are different in MySQL 8.0, with the new data dictionary implementation.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on table engine, I have created two tables using InnoDB and MyISAM

*MyISAM* uses the temporary folder on your OS, check the system variable `tmpdir` in my local config is set to: `/tmp`, so when I create a temporary table three random named files are created:

```
ubuntu:~$ ll /tmp/#*
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  /tmp/#sql4c0_6_1.frm
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  /tmp/#sql4c0_6_1.MYD
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  /tmp/#sql4c0_6_1.MYI
```

That files contains the table definition file (frm) the table data and indexes (MYD and MYI)

*InnoDB* engine uses a single file that contains another engine internals, but the table definition also is created in `tmpdir` path:

```
ubuntu:~$ ll /tmp/#*
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  /tmp/#sql4c0_6_0.frm   <-- InnoDB
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  /tmp/#sql4c0_6_1.frm   <-- MyISAM
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  /tmp/#sql4c0_6_1.MYD   <-- MyISAM
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql  /tmp/#sql4c0_6_1.MYI   <-- MyISAM
```

The data and indexes are stored in `/path/to/mysql/ibfileX` , the path is related to system variable `innodb_temp_data_file_path`